# How to make chartJs stacked bar always rounded when data is 0?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I came up with this Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2s09hqLu/ which has stacked rounded chart as I wanted.But problem is when a value is 0 in data array.It doesnt make it rounded.I always want it to be rounded how can I do that?

```
data: [20, 5, 0, 15, 12, 13]
```

[image]

As you can see here on the yellow its flat not rounded.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: because you are seeing below bar, it has value and its not rounded and upper bar has 0 value so its not showing. if you want you can set both rounded.

Comment: @turivishal I didnt understand clearly.Could u show me on my fiddle and come up with answer?

Comment: Added answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415397/8987128

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your Fiddle only line number `118`:
https://jsfiddle.net/r7hvn2ox/

**From:**

```
if (rounded){
```

**To:**

```
if (rounded || this._chart.data.datasets[1].data[this._index] == 0) {
```

> I know its fix for 2 datasets: [{}, {}] bars, but it will work perfectly in any of the values of datasets and also for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for answers.I tried below and worked perfectly for any amount of datasets.

```
var lastVisible;
  var datasetsLength = this._chart.data.datasets.length;
  this._chart.data.datasets.map((e,index)=>{
    lastVisible=datasetsLength-1;
    //to find the depth of datasets and get non-zero value
    for(var i=lastVisible;i>0;i--){
    if(!this._chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden){
      if(this._chart.data.datasets[i].data[this._index] != 0){
        lastVisible = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    } 
  })
```

Comment: I checked its not working in 3 datasets, when first datasets have value and other two datasets have not then its not working https://jsfiddle.net/qafLy2ct/

Comment: @turivishal I've encountered another problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423740/how-to-keep-rounded-bar-corners-when-data-is-filtered-chartjs come over here lets dicsucss here

Comment: @turivishal I updated my answer you can check it works

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional expression to `rounded` variable if its rendering specific item. This is not the best approach.

```js
var rounded = this._datasetIndex  === lastVisible || this._index === 2;
```

Alternatively you could compare values in each dataset

```
var cond = false;

if(this._datasetIndex === 0) {
  var datasets = this._chart.data.datasets;
  var dataset = datasets[this._datasetIndex];
  var currentData = dataset.data[this._index];
  var nextData = datasets[this._datasetIndex + 1].data[this._index]
  cond = currentData !== 0 && nextData === 0;
}

var rounded = this._datasetIndex  === lastVisible || cond;
```

Comment: I just replaced `var rounded = this._datasetIndex  === lastVisible` with above examples and did work. Perhaps you changed something else.